# Python threading module in loops with parameters?

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2

I am trying to create a crawler that crawl first 100 pages on a website:

My code is something like this:

```
def extractproducts(pagenumber):
    contenturl = "http://websiteurl/page/" + str(pagenumber)

    content = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())
    print pagehtml



pagenumberlist = range(1, 101)

for pagenumber in pagenumberlist:
    extractproducts(pagenumber)
```

How do i go about using threading module in this situation so that urllib will crawl X number of URLs at a time using mutli threads?

/newb out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you want to use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). There's a `Pool` you can use to execute multiple things in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Note: This many threads may make your system unresponsive for a while
p = Pool(100)

# First argument is the function to call,
# second argument is a list of arguments
# (the function is called on each item in the list)
p.map(extractproducts, pagenumberlist)
```

If your function returns anything, `Pool.map` will return a list of return values:

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1

results = Pool().map(f, [1, 4, 5])
print(results) # [2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: wow this was fast, and exactly what i was looking for. internet points for you fine sir.

Comment: @user1271067 If this was helpful for you, it would be nice if you clicked the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as "accepted" (and click the up arrow if you want).

Comment: Not enough rep. to give you an upvote at the moment. :/

Btw, multiprocessing doesn't seem to make urllib fetch pages any quicker, still seems to be fetching them one at a time.

Could just be my slow connection though, i'll rent a server with faster Internet and see if it's any better.

But directing me towards Multiprocessing was good enough i am sure i'll figure it out after going through the official docs and other questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @user1271067 - You could print something in your function before you make the request so you can at least see that they're happening in parallel. I would expect this to be at least a little bit faster.